# change size of md-switch in angular material

Tags: css, angular-material

I'm working with md-switch from Angular material :

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch

But the default switch looks small, and I want to resize it.

I tried to do add the `width` and the `height` properties, but it didn't work.

How can I do that ?

Comment: override  with adding new css property with the use of !important

Answer (score 0):

use this rule to custom the bar:

```
md-switch ._md-bar {
    left: 1px;
    width: 66px;
    top: 5px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and this rules to costum the circle:

```
md-switch ._md-thumb {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/zerubeus/pen/ONzWmj)**